# Compute the virtue of this feature for binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction, feature-selection

The end goal is to create a `binary classifier` that would output "YES" for around 10% of the instances (based on training data). The classifier would use `binary, continuous and maybe some categorical features`.

Currently I am extracting `a continuous feature` in range [0; 1] that should describe similarity between the real name of a product and its potential mention in a text field. I am trying out `different methods for extracting this feature` (Levenshtein distance and some other algorithms).

I am not sure what kind of `feature metrics` I should use to select (or at least approximate) the best extraction method for this feature; and the question would be:

**What kind of metrics should be used to reason about the best extraction method for a particular feature that would later be used with different binary classification algorithms if this feature is**

1. **binary**
2. **continuous**
3. **categorical**

Would I use something like `Pearson correlation` for 2) or would `Information gain` be a better metric?

The metrics should not be very classifier specific (I would like use the extracted features on multiple algorithms like decision tree, logical regression, neural network with small adjustments.).